# android change file executable property

Tags: android, permissions, executable

I download a pdf file from server with web service and save it in a file
then i try to open the file by PDFViwer but it dosent open
then i open eclipse file exploer i see the file permission is "-rw-----"
i try to change exec permission but it dosent

```
File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/aaa.pdf");
byte[] data = Base64.decode(evrakIcerikB64, 0);

boolean exec=myDir.setExecutable(true);
boolean read=myDir.setReadable(true);
boolean wri=myDir.setWritable(true);
```

how can i change file permission?

Comment: Why do you think exec permission is needed?

Comment: Because PDFViwer dosent open if no permission

Comment: i solved the problem to store the file in external storage Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()